# Issue regarding my contact form

Tags: php, forms, validation, contacts

I have a contact form on my page, now most of it is working fine, however I have create some validation which does some back end checking of string lengths if somehow the user bypasses the regular HTML maxlength argument for text inputs.

Here are my two problems:

1) If I enter numbers in a field then I automatically get a message saying ive gone over the max limit, which obviously shouldn't be getting executed.

2) The second problem Is that, when I get that message ( which was received wrong) it should of at least stopped the mail from being sent, since there was a problem, but it sends the email anyway!!

Feel free to go try it and see for your self:

http://eclipse-developers.com/v2/eclipse-developers.com/#contactUs

Here is the PHP script for my contact form:

```
// here we put in an if statement to check against missing variables (empty values)
        if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['message'])){

            $name=$_POST['name'];
            $organisation=$_POST['organisation'];
            $reference=$_POST['reference'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $subject=$_POST['subject'];
            $message=$_POST['message'];
            // here we are checking to see if that value anything and not just black.

            if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($subject) && !empty($message) ){  
                // this is doing a check for max length, its doing it in php just in case the user
                // cheats and bypasses the html check.

            if (strlen($name>31) || strlen($lname>31) || strlen($organisation>31) || strlen($email>51) || strlen($subject>31) || strlen($reference>31) || strlen($message>2001)){
                echo"sorry, max length for a field has been exceeded. Go back and try again</a><br><br>";
            }
            $to='skyrocketing132@yahoo.com';
            $emailsubject=$subject;
            $body=$name."\nCompany Name: ".$organisation."\nRef: ".$reference."\nMessage: ".$message;
            $headers= 'From: '.$email;

            // mails, if statement so if its true (mail did send)
                if  (mail($to,$emailsubject,$body,$headers)){
                    echo'Thanks for contacting us.';        
                }else{
                    echo'Sorry, an error occurred. Try again later.';
                }
            }
            } else{
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditions are wrong, you have:

```
strlen($name > 31)
```

This will first check if `$name` has a value higher than 31, which returns a boolean value of `true` or `false`. This is then cast to a string and the length of it is checked, which will always be higher than 0 and thus be true. It should be:

```
strlen($name) > 31
```

To prevent the e-mail from being sent, you have to abort after these conditions are true. Your code would become something like:

```
if (strlen($name) > 31 || strlen($lname) > 31 || strlen($organisation) >31 || strlen($email)>51 || strlen($subject)>31 || strlen($reference)>31 || strlen($message)>2001){
    echo"sorry, max length for a field has been exceeded. Go back and try again</a><br><br>";
} else {
    $to='skyrocketing132@yahoo.com';
    $emailsubject=$subject;
    $body=$name."\nCompany Name: ".$organisation."\nRef: ".$reference."\nMessage: ".$message;
    $headers= 'From: '.$email;

    // mails, if statement so if its true (mail did send)
    if  (mail($to,$emailsubject,$body,$headers)){
        echo'Thanks for contacting us.';        
    }else{
        echo'Sorry, an error occurred. Try again later.';
    }
}
```

Comment: change that line of code to this and it broke my page..error message:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '||' (T_BOOLEAN_OR) in /home/mmkbrida/public_html/v2/eclipse-developers.com/sent.php on line 48

Comment: if (strlen($name)>31) || strlen($organisation)>31) || strlen($email)>51) || strlen($subject)>31) || strlen($reference)>31) || strlen($message)>2001)){

Comment: @Panda You forgot to remove the ) after the max length. It should be as given in my answer.

Comment: will your above answer fix both my problems?

Comment: @Panda Yes, it will not send the e-mail if any of the max lengths are exceeded and it will no longer trigger on every input. Do you understand the mistake you made?

Comment: hold on, im looking through it now, to try to understand sir, thanks a lot for the help so far

Comment: Perfect! thanks a lot for your help, I understand what I did wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

**1) If I enter numbers in a field then I automatically get a message saying ive gone over the max limit, which obviously shouldn't be getting executed.**

Your conditions are wrong.

```
strlen($name>31)
```

Change to

```
strlen($name)>31
```

**2) The second problem Is that, when I get that message ( which was received wrong) it should of at least stopped the mail from being sent, since there was a problem, but it sends the email anyway!!**

Put an `exit;`/`die;` after a failure, or add `if/else` logic.

#### Force end

```
 if (strlen($name)>31 || strlen($lname)>31 || strlen($organisation)>31 || strlen($email)>51 || strlen($subject)>31 || strlen($reference)>31 || strlen($message)>2001){
     echo"sorry, max length for a field has been exceeded. Go back and try again</a><br><br>";
    exit;
 }
```

#### if/else logic

```
 if (strlen($name)>31 || strlen($lname)>31 || strlen($organisation)>31 || strlen($email)>51 || strlen($subject)>31 || strlen($reference)>31 || strlen($message)>2001){
     echo"sorry, max length for a field has been exceeded. Go back and try again</a><br><br>";
 } else {
    //Attempt email send
 }
```